# Mollifiers: Integral Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Why do these integrals converge:
>   $$\varphi\in\mathcal{C}_0^\infty:\quad\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau\varphi(s)\mathrm{d}s\to\varphi(0)\quad(\tau\geq0)$$

I tried to figure it out via substituting:
$$\frac{1}{\tau}\int_0^\tau\varphi(s)\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^1\varphi(\tau\hat{s})\mathrm{d}\hat{s}$$
but couldn't see why these should converge then.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you just want to know why/that/if the convergence in your last equation really holds? If you just want to show the **first** convergence, you only need continuity of $\varphi$ in $0$ (and measurability), you do not need to perform any substitutions.

Comment: I want the first convergence to prove but why is continuity in zero enough there and how can I see that? I mean it is dominated by $\frac{1}{t}\varphi(t)$ for $t\in(0,1]$ and by $1\cdot\varphi(t)$ for $t\in(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By continuity, there is $\delta >0$ with $|\varphi(0) - \varphi(s)| < \epsilon$ for $|s|<\delta$.

Hence, for $0\leq\tau < \delta$,

$$
\bigg| \frac{1}{\tau} \int_0^\tau \varphi(s) \, ds - \varphi(0)\bigg| \leq \frac{1}{|\tau|}\int_0^\tau |\varphi(s) - \varphi(0)| \, ds \leq \epsilon,
$$
because the integrand is bounded by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ah so simple, thanks! :D